# Prepositional Mood vs Subjunctive Mood vs Complex Object

Tags: grammar

What differences do we have in sentences below expressing the same mood and the same sense using different ways to express the same things by using different grammar:

1. She demanded him to buy that book.
2. She demanded that he should buy that.
3. She demanded he buy that book.

Comment: (3) is grammatical, though (3a) _She demanded that he buy that book_ would be better. (2) is bad because of the mismatch between strong _demand_ and weak _should_; again, (3a) is better, since the modal is already present in _demand_, which means, roughly, _(say (must `VP`)_. And (1) is simply ungrammatical; _demand_ does not take an indirect object with the Dative alternation.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of **demand** is *that which* the demand requires.

She demanded {something}.

The {something} can be a tangible thing:

> She demanded **a better seat**, one without a column blocking her view of the stage.
>
> She demanded **money**.

The {something} can also be an action that someone must perform.

When the demand is not a thing, such as a better seat, or money, but an action which is to be carried out by another person, that action is expressed by a clause, and the verb can be marked as not being in the indicative mood but in the subjunctive:

> The judge demanded *that he **pay** a fine of $100*.

There is also the pattern **to demand {something} *of* someone**.

> What was demanded of them?

That sentence means, *What were they required to do*?

The prepositional phrase **of {someone}** is required. Putting the {someone} in an objective declension (him, them, me, etc) and omitting the preposition is not an idiomatic way to refer to the {someone} who must obey the **demand**.

> The judge demanded of him *that he **pay** a fine of $5000 and **forfeit** his driver's license for one year*.

In contemporary English **should** normally expresses a strong recommendation or an urging, and therefore (to my American ear at least) it does not partner well with **demand**, which expresses a command, an order, a requirement that must be obeyed.